# How I can set up Jmeter to give me daily results

Tags: jmeter, dashboard

I've started using Jmeter to run daily performance tests, and have also just figured out how to produce an HTML dashboard.

What I need to do now is find a way to run Jmeter every day, producing an HMTL dashboard of the results, but with comparisons of the results of the last few days. This would mean adding to the data of existing files instead of creating a new HTML dashboard every day.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In your test plan, set the HTML dashboard to save the result to a local file. Then use a simple cron job to run a simple script. Let that script run the JMX from command line, then copy the stored HTML result to a persistent storage and maybe rename it with the date or something. Then you get a folder with all the results of each day.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is adding your JMeter test under [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) control.

Jenkins provides:

1. Flexible mechanism of [scheduling a job](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Jenkins/Jenkins_Scheduling_Job.php)
2. There is a [Performance Plugin for Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which automatically analyses current and previous builds and displays performance trend chart on JMeter Dashboard

   [image: JMeter Jenkins Performance Report Trend]

---

Alternatively you can schedule JMeter runs using i.e. [Windows Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) and compare the current run with the previous one using Merge Results plugin

[image: JMeter Merge Results Compare 2 builds]

Comment: Thanks for that. Can this be done on RunDeck as well?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent of Performance Plugin for RunDesk however you should be able to use MergeResults tool instead.